# How can I check if the windows-login-screen is shown with a c# windows-service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I would like to create a C#-service to log me in when the windows login-screen is shown. Is it possible to detect the windows login-screen with C#?

Comment: `windows login-screen is shown` You mean whenever the system is turned on u need to start u r start ur windows servies?

Comment: The windows login window is run within a process called LSASS that is isolated from all other processes. You can not do a custom authentication service, you should do it driver level somehow. If you want to do custom logging consider monitoring windows event log

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont want to create an own login-screen. I want to detect only if i am able to log in when the system has booted. After that, I want to fill the user and password field with c#. Is there any way to work with the LSASS process to check if user is logged out and has to fill the login-fields?

Comment: Use OpenInputDesktop to check for locked screen, like const int DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 256;
      IntPtr hwnd = OpenInputDesktop(0, false, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP);

      if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
      { // hence you code